# Capitalize fields of study?

Tags: capitalization

Do I say "I study computer science," or "I study Computer Science"? Similarly, "I really liked that computer science course," vs. "I really liked that Computer Science course."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Below user Robusto's foregoing answer, user  Clément requests sources which I provide here:

- An Internet search yielded [this](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=668467&page=2) which then recommended [this by the University of Sussex](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/capsandabbr/caps):

  > (c) The names of languages are always written with a capital letter.
  >   Be careful about this; it's a very common mistake.
  >
  > > Juliet speaks English, French, Italian and Portuguese.
  > >     I need to work on my Spanish irregular verbs.
  > >     Among the major languages of India are Hindi, Gujarati and Tamil.
  > >     These days, few students study Latin and Greek.
  >
  > Note, however, that names of disciplines and school subjects are not capitalized unless they happen to be the names of languages:
  >
  > > I'm doing A-levels in history, geography and English.
  > >     Newton made important contributions to physics and mathematics.
  > >     She is studying French literature.
- [The University of Ottawa’s writing guide](http://www.uottawa.ca/language-services/writing-guide/capitalization/subject-areas-and-disciplines):

  > Subject areas and disciplines
  >
  > Subject areas like biology, sociology, engineering, women’s studies
  >   and psychology are common nouns and don’t normally take a capital
  >   letter.
  >
  > > The University of Ottawa has programs in an array of disciplines, from mathematics and medicine to chemistry and criminology.
  >
  > The same applies to broader areas:
  >
  > > Professor Doesitall has published extensively in the humanities, pure and applied sciences and arts.
  >
  > NOTE: Capitalize the first letter in disciplines and subject areas
  >   only:
  >
  > in an official academic unit title:
  >
  > > School of Psychology; Department of Theatre, etc.
  >
  > on a diploma or certificate:
  >
  > > …so and so has met all of the requirements of the Master’s in Linguistics
  >
  > and in lists of official degree titles:
  >
  > > The Department of Social Sciences offers these degrees: Honours Bachelor of Social Science; Master’s in Sociology…
- [The University College London’s Style guide for student recruitment communications](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/prospective-students/pams/audit-design/style-guide):

  > - References to organisations should begin with a lower-case letter unless the title is given in full. For example: ‘The Department of
  >     Mathematics offers several degree programmes. Staff in the department
  >     specialise in...’
  > - Only use initial capitalisation for job roles when singular e.g. ‘Students will be assigned a Personal Tutor. All tutors...’
  > - Academic subjects begin with a lower-case letter unless part of a title. For example: ‘If you are interested in studying mathematics at
  >     UCL, a GCE A level in Mathematics is required.’
- [The Boston College’s style guide](https://www.bc.edu/offices/omc/styleguide/capitalization.html):

  > Departments, offices, majors
  >
  > Academic subjects are lowercase, except when you are describing a
  >   subject that is also a language, culture, or religion.
  >
  > > She is a psychology major and English minor.
  > >
  > > He works in the psychology department and the Germanic studies
  > >     department.
  >
  > The formal names of departments, offices, programs, and institutions
  >   should be capitalized; on a second or general/informal reference,
  >   lowercase.
  >
  > > He works in the Department of Psychology.
  > >
  > > She works in the Office of Marketing Communications.
  > >
  > > You can pick up an application at the admissions office.

Answer (score 17):

It depends. If you are referring to the title of a course or a major field of study, in a formal sense, then capitalize it.

> I took Computer Science 101, which was
>   a survey course.

Otherwise, just leave it uncapitalized.

> I'm interested in studying computer
>   science.

Comment: do you have any source for that, or is it just by usage that you figured it out ?

Comment: @Clément Here is just one of many sources for "Chemistry 101" and "Economics 406": https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=9x1CsvEwOjcI.html