# Capitalization of school subjects

Tags: punctuation, capitalization

What is the rule determinating whether or not we need to capitalize them? 
Sometimes I see "Math" ; "Physics" in the middle of a sentence, and sometimes lower case is used.

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[Capitalize fields of study?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6246/capitalize-fields-of-study)* Also see *[Should “Applied Cryptography” be capitalized? Is it a proper noun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117144)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [here](http://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/capitalization-rules.html):

Generally, you should capitalise the names of school subjects only when you refer to a **specific** course:

- I am excited to study history this summer.
- I'll be taking History 101 at the community college.

But you **always** capitalise the names of languages:

- I am excited to study Russian this summer.

Comment: I think the rule is **"Capitalize Proper Nouns ; Else use lower case"**. In the reference you give : In "study history" , history is not a Proper Noun ; In "History 101" , IT is a Proper Noun of a Subject ; In "study Russian" , It is always a Proper Noun.

Comment: @Prem I agree. It surely applies here too.