# Is the title of a course capitalized if it has no specific name?

Tags: capitalization

Do the names of classes remain without capitalization if they are the simple names of subjects and not specific course titles?

The example that I am looking at is:

"She asked a question in calculus, but her teacher provided no assistance."

I understand that calculus as a subject is not capitalized, but does its status as a class change that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalization of school subjects](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/309224/capitalization-of-school-subjects)

Comment: I do realize that this could be considered a duplicate, but after extensive searching, the only answers I could find were the courses with numbers (e.g. History 101), and I was not sure if the subject name alone would ever be capitalized. The second part of the answer I received was what I was looking for and could not find elsewhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Capitalize fields of study?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6246/capitalize-fields-of-study)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of a class is capitalized when you're using it as the name of a class.  If the name of a class is a common word or phrase, when you're using it to refer to something other than the class, it would not be capitalized.

Examples:

*I stopped studying math after high school.  I got as far as calculus.*

*Professor Leibniz teaches Calculus I, Calculus II and Discrete Mathematics.*

*American history is my favorite subject.*

*American History, with Professor Clarke, is my favorite class.*

Note: these kinds of sentences can be ambiguous when spoken, but when written, the capitalization can make the meaning clear.

*I hate multivariate statistics* (the subject)

*I hate Multivariate Statistics* (a specific class)