# Academic subject capitalization rules

Tags: capitalization, academia

I'm a little confused on when and when not to capitalize academic titles.

For example do you say

> "I am a Finance major."

or

> "I am a finance major."

Also does it change if it is

> "I am majoring in Finance."

or

> "I am majoring in finance."

Comment: "Finance" isn't really an academic title, though.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. I believe you may find the answer in *[Should "Applied Cryptography" be capitalized? Is it a proper noun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117144/should-applied-cryptography-be-capitalized-is-it-a-proper-noun)* or in *[Capitalize fields of study?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6246)* ; it's a matter of style.